# Preserve li width when child element hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a simple pagination control like below

http://jsfiddle.net/JLkJ6/1/

```
<ul class="c-work-list-pagination">
    <li class="link prev">
        <a href="#">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page">
        <span>Page</span>
        <span id="spnPage">0</span>
        <span>of</span>
        <span id="spnTotalPages">3</span>
    </li>
    <li class="link next">
        <a href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to be able to hide the A elements (Previous/Next) inside the li when there are no previous or next pages to show. When i apply display:none to the A tag the LI does not preserve its 33% width.

I think it's something simple but i'm lost at the moment ! Thanks for any info.

Comment: Have u tried min-width?

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `display:none;` you may use `visibility:hidden;`